# Awk 'value in array' returns match, but 'print array' outputs an OFS delimited blank, how do I print the array elements?

Tags: arrays, bash, awk

I have some genomics data with format: `chromosome"\t"position"\t"feature`.
Each feature is a member of a class, defined in a reference file. I want to output a file with format `class"\t"chromosome"\t"position"\t"feature`

Genomics files:

```
$ head *Y.tsv
chrY    8143806 HAL1B
chrY    15923083        LTR25-int
```

Reference file:

```
$ head /home/software/RepBase20.05.fasta/humrep_names.ref
HERVH   ERV1    Eutheria
X21_LINE        CR1     Mammalia
```

Code:

```
awk '
{FS=OFS="\t"}
NR==FNR{a[$1]="";a[$1,1]=$1;a[$1,2]=$2;a[$1,3]=$3; next}
$3 in a{print a[$1,2],$1,$2,$3}
' /home/software/RepBase20.05.fasta/humrep_names.ref *Y.tsv
```

Output is printed, suggesting that the array was read in properly and a match was found, but `a[$1,2]` is blank; output:

```
chrY    21596689        L1M2A_5
chrY    16760406        HERV-K14CI
chrY    18692648        MER101_I
```

Why is a match being made with 'in', but the print shows no value? How can I print out the class (`a[$1,2]`) of each feature (`a[$1,1]` AND `$3`)?

Thanks!

Comment: You should set FS, etc. in a BEGIN block, and you are confused about arrays, especially pseudo-multi-demensional ones, and the meaning of the `in` operator. Get the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins

Comment: I surely am confused, thank you for your thorough, well thought out response which helped to clarify that confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely take a look to the book that Ed Morton recommends, but I think you had it more or less correct except you put `$1` where you meant `$3` in the print statement.

```
$ cat a.awk
# As mentioned in the comments, use BEGIN to only do this once
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }

# no change from yours
NR==FNR{ a[$1]=""; a[$1,1]=$1; a[$1,2]=$2; a[$1,3]=$3; next}

# a[$3,2] instead of a[$1,2]
$3 in a {print a[$3,2],$1,$2,$3}

$ cat file1.txt
HERVH   ERV1    Eutheria
X21_LINE        CR1     Mammalia

$ cat file2.txt
chrY    8143806 HAL1B
chrY    15923083        HERVH

$ awk -f a.awk file1.txt file2.txt
ERV1    chrY    15923083        HERVH
```